# LGTM config file with custom package

Tags: build

I’m new to [LGTM](https://lgtm.com). I like the idea of checking code quality, so I want to try it out on a project I follow a bit. The project mostly contains known packages, but also has some self-compiled code.

According to https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/analysis-faqs#dont-use-git-clone, I should use the following method:

```sh
$ curl -L https://github.com/axios/axios/archive/v0.18.1.tar.gz --output v0.18.1.tar.gz
```

I don’t know if that package follows LGTM’s example for C++ which is as follows (it comes from https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/cpp-extraction):

```yaml
extraction:
  cpp:
    prepare:
      packages: 
        - libboost-all-dev
        - bison
      configure:
        command:
          - ./bootstrap
          - ./configure --with-modules="" --without-lua
```

The problem I have is how and where do I put this custom package in the build configuration? I don’t know the package so for now I’ll use `package_a` as an example.

Normal workflow for building should be:

```sh
$ curl -L https://github.com/developer/package_a/archive/package_a_v0.1.1.tar.gz --output package_a_v0.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf package_a_v0.1.1.tar.gz -C package_a
$ cd package_a && sudo ./waf configure build install && cd ..
```

I’m unable to figure out what part is `prepare`, if it is a `package` or not, `configure` or `index` (not mentioned in the example above, but it is on this page: https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/lgtm.yml-configuration-file#example-lgtm.yml-file).

Is this the only step (to create a package), or are there multiple steps (e.g., in the form of some commands under `prepare` and some other under `configure`, etc.)?